# error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I've just started using Hadoop and I tried this tutorial http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Usage

but when I try to compile the Java program the error shows up.

I installed openjdk version "1.8.0_131", and my environment variables are

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```